# Cannot send or receive SMS on Galaxy Young Duos, someone help?

Tags: sms, calls

I bought a Samsung Galaxy Young Duos S6102. The problem is I cannot receive nor send SMS. Sometimes, I cannot receive calls, nor call someone. I have tried rebooting my phone, changing the sim card and updating the phone's software, and at first it works, however, after a few minutes I encounter the same problem again. Can please someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your carrier. Have you got the latest APN settings, and the correct carrier settings? You can confirm them with the Network. Since you have tried updating firmware, and changing SIM it is either your network provider or a hardware defect, I would guess. Perhaps return to the vendor and see what can be done?

Comment: Yes, I've got the latest APN settings and the correct carrier settings. Thanks, I'm going to check it my vendor. But do you think there's something I can do other than checking it with him (vendor)?

Comment: You could try an alternative text app like hangouts, or GoSMS etc, but if you can't make or receive calls also it seems like something is fundementally wrong. Do you keep losing reception? Does your 3g work ok?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it's up, most of the time it's down. Also, sometimes the signal looks okay but if I try to send a message or call someone, it doesn't work.